# problem with dependency turtlebot_node

Tags: catkin, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm working with Groovy on Turtlebot (create base).

How could I add the dependency turtlebot_node to my package? I have done the following:

**CMakeLists.txt** of my package:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)   
project(beginner_tutorials)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package (catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs turtlebot_node)
```

**Package.xml** of my package :

```
<build_depend>turtlebot_node</build_depend>
<run_depend>turtlebot_node</run_depend>
```

However when I execute catkin_make in my catkin_ws,I have **the following error**:

```
turtlebot@turtlebot:~$ cd ~/catkin_ws/

turtlebot@turtlebot:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make

Base path: /home/turtlebot/catkin_ws

Source space: /home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/src

Build space: /home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/build

Devel space: /home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/devel

Install space: /home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/install

#### #### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/turtlebot/catkin_ws /build" ####

-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/devel

-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/groovy

-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/groovy

-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built

-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/build/test_results

-- catkin 0.5.65

-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on

-- ~~ traversing 1 packages in topological order: -- ~~ - beginner_tutorials

-- +++ processing catkin package: 'beginner_tutorials'

-- ==> add_subdirectory(beginner_tutorials)

CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):

Could not find a configuration file for package turtlebot_node.

Set turtlebot_node_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file for turtlebot_node. The file will have one of the following names:

turtlebot_nodeConfig.cmake
turtlebot_node-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first): prueba/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! make: * [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1 Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

Can anyone help me please? I have no idea what is wrong with it.

I would appreciate any feedback.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/123486/problem-with-dependency-turtlebot_node/) by [albarranco](https://answers.ros.org/users/5345/albarranco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-01-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bchr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4609/bchr/) on 2014-01-28**:
What are you trying to do exactly? I think that turtlebot_node is no longer used with groovy.

**Comment by [albarranco](https://answers.ros.org/users/5345/albarranco/) on 2014-01-28**:
okk,thanks. I only want to probe a file that makes that turtlebot turn on groovy but I don't know it (the file is for electric and subcribes to turtlebot_node)

**Comment by [bchr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4609/bchr/) on 2014-01-28**:
Try to check this: http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/TurtleBot (choose groovy).

**Comment by [albarranco](https://answers.ros.org/users/5345/albarranco/) on 2014-01-28**:
ok,thank you very much for everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that `catkin` can't find `turtlebot_node` in your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`. In theory, you just need to make sure that `turtlebot_node` is installed (e.g. `rospack list-names | grep turtlebot`), and that your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` contains the path to `turtlebot_node`'s install directory. You can check the current value of `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` by typing:

```
echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

To update it, just type:

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/path/to/dir:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

However, in your case, it seems that `turtlebot_node` was removed with Groovy, so you should not even try to depend on it. For more information on turtlebot (which seems to be what you actually need), check the official documentation [here](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot) and [there](http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/TurtleBot).

Here is a [similar problem](http://answers.ros.org/question/113291/no-turtlebot_node-in-hydro/).

---

Originally posted by [bchr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4609/bchr/) with karma: 596 on 2014-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0